# How to flow content like the text in a multi-column PDF, i.e. with columns and page breaks

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

CSS has `columns` attributes that flow text in a more complicated way than left-to-right wrapping. What I want to do is to limit the column height, so that once the text would exceed that height, it flows into a new row of columns. In other words, I want to recreate the experience of reading a multi-column PDF with just HTML and CSS, and with the dynamic text flowing that occurs when you resize a browser window. In still other words, how can I flow content like it was targeting paged media?

Here's a diagram of what I mean:
[image: Diagram showing two rows of three columns each, with arrows showing the path text flows through the boxes: left-to-right with wrapping in each column, left-to-right among columns, and top-to-bottom among rows.]

Is there currently any way to do that without resorting to divvying up text content into multiple block elements using Javascript?

Comment: No, there is not. You can have columns, but not colums *and* page breaks like that.

Comment: @Johannes What about sticking a block element with `column-span: all` styling? That breaks the columns and flows like I describe, but it's only at fixed positions in the document. It seems like layout engines *can* wrap like this

Comment: The problem lies in the dynamic continuation of the text from the last column of the first row to the first column of the next row – that's not possible with HTML and CSS.

Comment: It *nearly* was a thing but the W3C dropped it. [CSS Regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/#:~:text=The%20CSS%20Regions%20module%20allows,and%20outputs%20of%20this%20fragmentation.)

Comment: Too bad! Should be possible to use js to insert `column-span: all` divs at appropriate intervals though. Just hate to have to reflow on resize like that.